# Передать в прототип двумерный массив

Tags: массивы, c, c++

Задание: Функция заполняет массив случайными числами после чего основная программа ищет кол-во элементов больше заданного по главной диоганали:

Ошибки вот такие компилятор выдает:

> In function 'int func(int*, int,
> int)':
>
> [Error] invalid types 'int[int]' for
> array subscript
>
> [Error] invalid types 'int[int]' for
> array subscript

на вот эти строки в прототипе

> ```
> array[i][j] =rand()%25-5;
>
> cout<<array[i][j]<<" ";
> ```

```
#include <iostream>

#include <conio.h>

#include <time.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <clocale>

using namespace std;

int func(int * array, int dim1, int dim2)

{

srand(time(NULL));

for (int i = 0; i< dim1; i++)

{

for (int j = 0; j<dim2; j++)

{

array[i][j] =rand()%25-5;

cout<<array[i][j]<<" ";

}

cout << '\n';

}

return *array;

}

int main()

{

int max,col=0;

int m[5][5];

func((int*)m,5,5);

cout<<"Введите максимальный элемент"<<endl;

cin>>max;

for (int i=0;i<5;i++)

{

cout<<"m[i][i]="<<m[i][i]<<endl;

if((m[i][i]>=0)and (m[i][i]>max)) col++;

}

cout<<"Кол-во="<<col<<endl;

}
```

Comment: @Анатолийй, а на and транслятор не ругался? В Си это &&.

Comment: @paulgri, тут используется компилятор C++, а в C++ есть ключевое слово `and`.

Comment: Действительно, век живи - век учись ))

Comment: Что здесь делает тег [C]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто указатель на первый элемент не поможет: это будет `int *`, т.е. внутри функции массив будет выглядеть одномерным. Из-за этого обращаться к элементам придётся так: `array[i * 5 + j]`, где 5 — количество элементов в одной строке массива. Дело в том, что двумерный массив — это двойной указатель `int **`, но если описать его так, то внутри функции вы получите массив указателей — это не соответствует логической организации "настоящего" двумерного массива.

Альтернатива: описать параметр как `int array[5][5]`, но это подойдет только в случае, если исходный массив **всегда** имеет точно такие размеры. Поэтому лучше первый вариант.

Comment: Хороший ответ.

Comment: @avp, спасибо)

Comment: Отличный ответ!

Comment: "Дело в том, что двумерный массив — это двойной указатель `int **`" - это **грубейшая** ошибка! Языковый двумерный массив `int [M][N]` не имеет никакого отношения к "двойному указателю".

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо передать указатель на первый элемент массива. Для этого необходимо обратиться к первому элементу и взять его адрес.

```
func(&m[0][0],5,5);
```

Comment: Однако обращения вида

    array[i][j]

внутри `func` все равно недопустимы.

Comment: Судя по всему, здесь у нас вполне себе С++, так что как выход - 

    typedef vector<vector<int>> IntMatrix;

    int func(IntMatrix &array);

Answer (score 0):

Оптимальный ответ на этот вопрос может отличаться существенно между С и С++. Так как код написан на С++, то один из вариантов ответа таков:

Если вы хотите, чтобы ваша функция принимала массивы run-time размера, но при этом хотите иметь возможность использовать ее со встроенными многомерными массивами (т.е. массивами `int[N][M]`), то один из вариантов решения подразумевает объявление функции в виде

```
int func(int *const *array, int dim1, int dim2)
{
  ...
  array[i][j];
  ...
}
```

А затем использование дополнительного временного массива "указателей на строки" при необходимости передачи встроенного 2D массива

```
int m[5][5];

int *const rows[] = { m[0], m[1], m[2], m[3], m[4] };
func(rows, 5, 5);
```